# Python splitting to the newline character

Tags: python, string, split, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have an html file that I am just retrieving the body of text from.
I would like to print it in one single line.

Right now I print it like this:

```
for line in newName.body(text=True):
    print line
```

This gives me everything in the body that I would like is to print like:

```
for line in newName.body(text=True):
    print line[257:_____] # this is where i need help
```

Instead of ____ or choosing another number as the end, I want it to go to the newline character, so it looks like:

```
for line in newName.body(text=True):
    print line[257:'\n']
```

However that dosent work.
How can I make it work?

The text which I am working in is located in:

```
body
    pre
        The text I want
    /pre
/body
```

Comment: _"i would like to print one single line"_ does `print newName.body(text=True)[257]` work as expected?

Comment: no this produces an error "list index out of range"

Comment: posted the wrong error message

the correct one is "ValueError: substring not found"

Comment: Are you sure using a regexp wouldn't provide a better solution ? As it seems you're getting text of body of a HTML document and trying to get from the 127 character up until '\n' - Surely the reality is those bits of text are really part of the structure of the document which implies Xpath or similar would be a better option - perhaps you could provide a snippet of the HTML page you're trying to extract.

Comment: @sotapme the code is something like 
    '<pre>
    cptn
    cheesebox
    loves
    cerial
    </pre>'

these are all onseparate lines but i coudlt figure out how to make it appear like code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`.partition()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to get the first line:

```
first_line = newName.body.getText().partition("\n")[0]
```

assuming `newName` is a `BeautifulSoup` object. It is usually named `soup`.

To get text from the first `<pre>` tag in the html:

```
text = soup.pre.string
```

To get a list of lines in the text:

```
list_of_lines = text.splitlines()
```

If you want to keep end of line markers in the text:

```
list_of_lines = text.splitlines(True)
```

To get i-th line from the list:

```
ith_line = list_of_lines[i]
```

note: zero-based indexing e.g., `i = 2` corresponds to the 3rd line.

Comment: this produces error
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partition'"

Comment: @MysterMyster: try `.getText()`. It should also work on old `BeautifulSoup` versions.

Comment: and that produces 
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: ok so now if i do 

    first_line = newName.body.getText().partition('\n')[2] it returns all the text from line 257 on  just like before but now print first_line[257:]

Comment: @MysterMyster: `.partition()` returns 3-tuple. Always. You can't get IndexError with the code from my answer. If you want to get a list of lines, you could use `.splitlines()`. But extracting content from an html using a line number is very fragile. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14801057/edit) to include what html markup do you see around the text that you want to extract.

Comment: .splitlines()
worked to remove the '\n' but the program still does not just end there it continues on to print the rest of the file where i only want that one line

Comment: around the text is the pre  /pre

Comment: would like to thank you for your help i finally got it using    first_line = newName.body.getText().partition("\n")[2]     followed by 
 FL2 = first_line.splitlines()
followed by
  pprint.pprint(FL2[10:11])

i can not thank you enough for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: one more question   how can i make that a string so i could write it out to a text or use it to save the file as that name?

Comment: @MysterMyster: I've updated the answer to show how to get lines that are in `<pre>` tag. Each line *is* a string.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that your HTML file has more than one line.  The web page may be laid out in lines, but the structure of the page doesn't have to match the structure of the markup and vice versa.

Just to be sure, try this:

> print len(newName.body(text=True).split('\n'))

If the value is >1, then you should be able to get the line you need like:

> newName.body(text=True).split('\n')[257]

Maybe not the most graceful way, but it works, if there are in fact multiple lines.

Comment: the first line produces attributeError: 'resultset' object has no attribute split

Answer (score 2):

Is it that you want `line[127:line.find('\n')]` as you are sure it's from `127` then equally you must be sure there's a `\n`.